# DateTime CompareTo operation throwing error

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I am trying to compare current date with a calculated date from offset as shown below. **The line throws an exception, enters catch block but exception is null.** I cannot find what is the exception because of it

```
DateTime.UtcNow.Date.CompareTo(new UtcDateTime(startDate.AddDays(activity.DueInDaysOffset.GetValueOrDefault()))) > 0
```

startDate is date from DB

activity.DueInDaysOffset is an integer - positive/negative.

UtcDateTime is a class from 'Microsoft.CommonDataService' used for conversion.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Well what does the exception say?

Comment: Please at least post a complete code sample. And what is `UtcDateTime`. What's `activity`? How are we supposed to answer without knowing any of that?

Comment: the exception variable is null and that is strange

Comment: activity.DueInDaysOffset is just an integer, positive or negative. UtcDateTime is a class used for conversion

Comment: You should post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Sach can you explain why you mark it as a null reference exception. Do you think i was so dumb to post a null reference exception here ?

Comment: @Sach The execution of this line throws error, it enters catch block, but the exception object is null. I cannot find what is the exception and you are marking it as null reference exception.

Comment: @RaviSankarRao you should take it up with Servy who did so. As per your second question, well, it remains to be seen.

Comment: @Sach the post is minimal, complete. This is iniside a function that takes activity and start date as parameters. And i have edited the question

Comment: @Sach Oh...i am sorry. I misinterpreted it

Comment: It's neither complete nor verifiable.

Comment: @servy I suggest you to read the post again before marking it as a duplicate.

Comment: @RaviSankarRao The alternative is your question being closed as unclear, because the question is a real mess.

Comment: @Servy Great...Thanks for your help guys. This was an awesome learning.

Answer (score -2):

Without knowing the rest of your code, I would guess that either startDate or activity is null. Verify that both variables have values.

Comment: Of-course i had checked them. The problem is the execution throws error, enters catch block and the exception object is null.

Comment: Exception objects are never null. Maybe you checked too early.